# Get user avatar (exchange,outlook, office) from specific user using c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am building function to getting avatar (byte array, base 64, url) from exchange/outlook/office/portal. I am using c# for this app,please help me, thanks

Comment: Using which API? EWS? Graph? Outlook Object Model?

Comment: https://nam.delve.office.com/  from this bro     for image i.stack.imgur.com/qqSvJ.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqSvJ.png

Comment: That is the picture of what you *want* to access. What is the *API* that you are using or planning to use?

Comment: I think this server open api for get user infomation, Iam using c# to write api get any avatar picture from this system